# how to increment counter++ array java an then rest it

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count=0;
        int[]counter={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int[]h={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

        for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++){
            if(count==3){
                count=0;
            }
            count ++;

            if(i==2||i==6||i==9)
                h[i]=count;
            System.out.println(h[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
3
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
```

But I want:

```
0
0
3
0
0
0
3
0
0
3
```

I would like to know how you increment counter and then rest it to 0. I do not want to set the value directly to 3.

edited: what i want to achieve is i have list view on android app and on click on list item i want to remove that item , that is not problem but i want to create a condition that after 3 click on each item then remove that item from list view
so i think i need to compare position to arraylist that contain 0 zero values so i want to say if position==araylist item then increase counter by 1 then make another condition if the counter is more than 3 the remove that item from list view

thank you

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Always use debugger to test

Comment: where is debugger

Comment: Wanted to write that you should add your `count=0` to the second `if` statement, but that would make your middle number to be 4...

Comment: ok will edit my question and explain what i need to achive thanks for all and the question will be same

Comment: why don't you set `3` for `i=2,6,9` others for `0`?

Comment: Why is h[9] equals 3? Shouldn't it be 2? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have edited my question i need it to use it for list view item in android app so because if i set counter to 3 then listview will count any click on different item as a click then sum it so if an item clicked once it still count but i want to if an item clicked once it will count once for that item and only remove it when the count reached 3

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking a question specifically about your Android app and what you are trying to achieve with it?

Comment: i will ask aswell but have to wait but i do not believe it is possible but i thought i probably use some of people with programming skills and algorithm

Comment: @SeekingKnowleges Describe what you want to do, else you may as well hard code it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count=0;
        int[]counter={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int[]h={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

        for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++){
            //if(i==2||i==6||i==9)
             //   h[i]=count;
             if(count==3)
                count=0;
            else
              count++;
           if(i==2||i==6||i==9)
                h[i]=count;
           if(i == 9)
               h[i]++;     
                System.out.println(h[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Once check this code.

Comment: kvk thank you i do not want it to hard coded because i do not know the size of the array so i could increased or decreased in size in your case if i add ||11 then gives 0 zero but thanks may be my question is stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

ok friends thanks all i have solved my listview problem i tried same idea to  solve this problem so we need 2 dimensional array the first one is to how many times it repeat in my case is 3 so i set it to less than 3 and d rest each time add 1 to the position i specified below is my code and hope will hellp others and thanks for great support

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[]h={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
for(int g=0;g<3;g++){
        for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++){
            if(i==2||i==6||i==9||i==13)
                h[i]+=1;
        }}
        for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++){

            System.out.println(h[i]);}
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is also hard coded one. Can you briefly explain me about your logic?

Comment: thi is not hard coded at all no mater what is the size of you array thehis code will remain the same but in your case if a increase array listy then i have to add new code

Comment: ok if you increase the size of the array of decrease it does not affect any changing code and will work, so in my case i want to add 3 to specific element of the array but i want to each time search and find that element and add 1 so the loop is going only once that is why we need outer loop and set it to 3 so it search the arraylist and find that element 3 times so if you want to search 5 times then the result will be 5 to each element specified so only need to change outer loop from 3 to 5 and the rest of code is same